# how to set middleware in next js

Tags: next.js, middleware

I hope you are very well.
I am developing an app in next js and I need to implement a solution to prevent a CSFR attack, I found a tutorial where it is implemented here I leave the linkd of the information.(https://dev.to/adelhamad/csrf-protection-in-nextjs-1g1m)

I wanted to implement it like this but I get error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkR9Q.png)

This is the csrf.js file in the path /src/csrf.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Ubb.png)

Here is the login API in /src/pages/api/auth/login.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiQlr.jpg)

Here the frontend /src/pages/login.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZmA5.jpg)

I don't know what could be happening, thank you in advance.

For the process I used the "csurf" library: "^1.11.0", I don't know if there's something else I'm neglecting.